# Is it possible to use the menu to call wxDirPickerCtrl's open dialog in wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

I created a wxDirPickerCtrl item to browse the directory. I would like to add a menu item in **File** | **Open** and that would somehow link to the wxDirPickerCtrl item to open the dialog. Is that possible? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`wxDirPickerCtrl` just opens a standard `wxDirDialog`, so if you want to open it in a response to a menu command, just use this class directly.

Comment: Do you mean I should not use `wxDirPickerCtrl` and use a normal button which uses `wxDirDialog` instead?

Comment: No, I don't mean this. You should open `wxDirDialog` yourself and set your `wxDirPickerCtrl` to the directory selected in if if this is what you want. It does result in a strange UI, but it's strange because you use a menu command to change the value of a control in a window, which is pretty unusual.

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean. Please could you kindly write some code to explain it? Many thanks!

Comment: There is really nothing complicated here. In your `wxEVT_MENU` handler for "File|Open", create and show `wxDirDialog` and then, if it wasn't cancelled, call `SetDirName()` on your existing `wxDirPickerCtrl` instance. What exactly is not clear?

Comment: I think your answer is 'not possible' then. i.e. I cannot do something like `wxDirPickerCtrl.getDialog().ShowModal()` (apparently I make up the getDialog function). It's like in Microsoft Word you have a Open button in the toolbar, and also you can use File | Open to open a document.

Comment: It's not possible to do exactly what you wrote, but doing what I described would result in _exactly_ the same effect from the user point of view. So, again, you're just approaching the problem from the wrong end, stop thinking about `wxDirPickerCtrl` and think about what do you actually want to achieve.